# .htaccess redirect losing query string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess that looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

I was hoping that would make all non-www urls redirect to the www version, as well as giving a tidy query string on the end. So these urls:

```
http://site.com/index.php?query=test/page
http://www.site.com/index.php?query=another/test/page
```

Would both redirect to:

```
http://www.site.com/test/page
http://www.site.com/another/test/page
```

Respectively.

However, everything is just redirecting to:

```
http://www.site.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ignores the query string in the url. So you will need to change your rules as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^/index[.]php$ /%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Make sure you include the QSA flag on the first rule